# Shape missing using pic in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

Why the shape `(sB)` is `unknown` in the following code ?
How to avoid this ?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{pics/.cd,
    % Marque croix
    Cross/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
        code = {%
        \draw[#2,rotate=45,scale=1.4] (0,#1 pt) -- (0,-#1 pt) ;
        \draw[#2,rotate=-45,scale=1.4] (0,#1 pt) -- (0,-#1 pt) ;
        }
    },
    Cross/.default={2 and black}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Segment}{mO{}}{%
    \begin{scope}[#2]
    \path    (0,0) coordinate (sA) pic {Cross={1.5 and gray}}
        -- (#1,0) coordinate (sB) pic {Cross={1.5 and gray}} ;
    \draw (sA)--(sB) ; % Can't reuse (sB)
    \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \Segment{1.5}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your second question on avoiding: `\path    (0,0) coordinate (sA) pic {Cross={1.5 and gray}};
    \path (#1,0) coordinate (sB) pic {Cross={1.5 and gray}} ;` in the definition of `\Segment`

Comment: @HarishKumar is not possible to use two or more `pics` on same `path`?

Comment: @Ignasi Why not? Try `\draw (0,0) -- pic[pos=0] {Cross={1.5 and gray}}
                 pic[pos=1] {Cross={1.5 and gray}} (#1,0);` for example.

Comment: @HarishKumar Mixing your to remarks, on can do : ` \draw   (0,0) coordinate (sA) -- (#3,0)  coordinate (sB)
  \foreach \i in {0,1} {pic[pos=\i] {Cross={1.5 and gray}}};
`

Comment: @HarishKumar OK, forget my question. Mark solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. The internal command `\iftikz@node@is@pic` is not reset after a `pic` on a path so any subsequent nodes (coordinates are nodes) are parsed as pics and consequently nothing is done.

A temporary fix (and not guaranteed to work in every possible use case) is to put the following (with appropriate category code changes) in the preamble:

```
\def\tikz@do@after@node{\tikz@node@is@picfalse\tikz@scan@next@command}
```

Comment: I was not able to find a bug report, so I did it here : https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/341/

Comment: There is another workaround to this bug that I have seen somwehre on TeX.SX (the author was @percusse I think), we can isolate the `pic` in a group like this `{pic[..]{..}}`. For exemple in OP we can do `\path (0,0) coordinate (sA) {pic{Cross={1.5 and gray}}} -- (#1,0) coordinate (sB) pic{Cross={1.5 and gray}};`.