# I want to draw a dot / small sphere in a TikZ 3D Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I got a 3d coordinate system and I want to mark a point with a dot.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x = {(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},]
\draw[thick,->] (-15,0,0) -- (15,0,0) node[right] {x};
\draw[thick,->] (0,-12,0) -- (0,12,0) node[above] {y};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,-15) -- (0,0,50) node[right] {z};
\fill (0,0,5) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the result:

[image: bad dot]

but what i want is a sphere or a circle from the point of view:

[image: good dot]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

typical, 2 hours searching the internet. then after finally posting, 2 mins later i find the answer myself. but since it was so hard to find maybe it will be helpful to somebody else:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x = {(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)},]
\draw[thick,->] (-15,0,0) -- (15,0,0) node[right] {x};
\draw[thick,->] (0,-12,0) -- (0,12,0) node[above] {y};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,-15) -- (0,0,50) node[right] {z};
\draw plot [mark=*, mark size=10] coordinates{(0,0,5)}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i dont know how it works, but it does perfectly what i wanted:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

A `tikz-3dplot` solution that both sphere and circle, whose size can be changed, are shown here.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{120}{50}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, tdplot_main_coords,axis/.style={->},thick]
\draw[axis] (-1, 0, 0) -- (1, 0, 0) node [right] {$X$};
\draw[axis] (0, -1, 0) -- (0, 3, 0) node [right] {$Z$};
\draw[axis] (0, 0, -1) -- (0, 0, 1) node [above] {$Y$};

\node[draw=none,shape=circle,fill, inner sep=2pt] (d1) at (0,1,0){};  % circle

\tdplottransformmainscreen{0}{2}{0}
\shade[tdplot_screen_coords, ball color = red] (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy) circle (0.05);                                                                   % sphere
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `node` to put your points.

Using marks is perfect if you want to put points on lines, but if you want to put points outside of lines ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, varwidth, border=10]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2, x = {(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, y={(0cm,1cm)}, z={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}]
    \draw[thick,->] (-15,0,0) -- (15,0,0) node[right] {x};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-12,0) -- (0,12,0) node[above] {y};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-15) -- (0,0,50) node[right] {z};
    \path (0,0,5) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1]{};
    \path (1,0,5) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1]{};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note : You can read [this question/answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/217797/9335).