# How set TikZ circle radius in \node[circle]?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I know that with Ti*k*Z, we can specify the radius of a circle when a `\draw` command is used, as in:

```
 \draw[fill] (1,2) circle (3pt);
```

But how does one indicate the radius when you draw the circle by means of a `\node` command, as in the following?

```
 \node[fill,circle,label=below left:$x$] at (1,2) {};
```

For example, suppose I want a 3pt radius of the circle in this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill,circle,label=below left:$x$] at (1,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I prefer to see two ways of doing this: one way that would apply just to the particular (filled) circle, and a second way that could be used globally for the entire picture.

Comment: You can use `minimum width=3pt` to set a minimal width of `3pt`. However, the node may be larger than that. You could use `scale=0.3` or so to scale it down.

Comment: Copy directly from manual: `\draw (0,-2) node[minimum size=2cm,draw,circle] {circle};`

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, but this does not work for too small radii. The node will retain a width greater than the `minimum width`.

Comment: **Related**: [How to draw points in TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217797/how-to-draw-points-in-tikz)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A node with circle shape the circles radius equal to `minimum size/2`, of course if you set `inner sep` to zero. Node features can define local at node or as new style with `tikzpicture` options or globally with `tikzset` in preamble of a document. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
dot/.default = 6pt  % size of the circle diameter 
                    ]  
\node[dot,label=below left:radius 3pt] at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=5pt,label=below left:radius 5pt] at (3,0) {};
\draw[red, semitransparent] (0,0) circle[radius=3pt];% test of the radius size
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=#1,
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
dot/.default = 6pt % size of the circle diameter 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}                   ]  
\node[dot,label=below left:radius 3pt] at (0,0) {};
\node[dot=10pt,label=below left:radius 5pt] at (3,0) {};
\draw[red, semitransparent] (0,0) circle[radius=3pt];% test of the radius size
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that `minimum size` defines the diameter instead of the radii of the circle.

Comment: @lcgodoy, yes, ˛`minimum size˛define diameter of cirrcle.This is evident from my answer.

Answer (score 27):

Interesting, here a test of the commands, according to what I found that the dimension of the shapes in text nodes, in this case circle, depends on the `text_node_content_shape_dimmension` + `the_internal_separation (inner sep)`; as it defines itself the `minimum size`, it would only define the size if the dimension of the text + the internal separation are less than the `minimum size`; In this way, if we want to ensure that the dimension of the shape is determined by `the minimum size`, the value of the internal separation must subtract from the value corresponding to the text so that both summations are lower than the `minimun size`.

RESULT: Multiple option-results to see how the controls works for shape size even if it contains text.

[image]

MWE:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=2pt]},
        line width=0.1pt,
        fill opacity=0.2,
        text opacity=1,
    ]
    %Grid in pt units
    \draw[black!30,step=1pt] (0,0) grid (30pt,-120pt);
    \draw[black!80,step=10pt,line width=0.2pt] (0,0) grid (30pt,-120pt);
    \draw[|-|,line width=0.2pt] (0,0)++(0,3pt)-- ++(10pt,0) node[midway](n){};
    \draw[<-] (n.center) |- ++(10pt,5pt) node [anchor=180, inner sep=0pt]{\tiny \verb+10pt+};

    %Drawing a shape
    \draw[fill]
    (15pt,-5pt)
        circle (3pt)
        ++ (15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\draw[fill](x,y) circle (3pt);+};
    %Drawing a node
    \draw[blue]
    (15pt,-15pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$x$]{}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$x$]at(x,y){};+};

    \draw[blue!50!cyan]
    (15pt,-25pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$x$] {$x$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$x$]at(x,y){$x$};+};

    \draw[green!50!blue]
    (15pt,-35pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$x$, inner sep=0pt] {$x$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$x$,inner sep=0pt]at(x,y){$x$};+};

    \draw[green!50!black]
    (15pt,-45pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$, inner sep=0pt] {$h$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,inner sep=0pt]at(x,y){$h$};+};

    \draw[green!50!orange]
    (15pt,-55pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,inner sep=-1pt] {$h$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,inner sep=-1pt]at(x,y){$h$};+};

    \draw[orange]
    (15pt,-65pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6pt] {$h$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6pt]at(x,y){$h$};+};

    \draw[red]
    (15pt,-75pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt] {$h$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6pt,inner sep=0pt]at(x,y){$h$};+};

    \draw[red!50!black]
    (15pt,-85pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$, inner sep=-2] {$h$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,inner sep=-2]at(x,y){$h$};+};

    \draw[blue!50!black]
    (15pt,-95pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6, inner sep=-2] {$h$}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6,inner sep=-2]at(x,y){$h$};+};

    \draw[blue!50!purple]
    (15pt,-105pt)
        node [fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6, inner sep=-2] {}
        ++(15pt,0)
        node[anchor=180, font=\tiny]{\verb+\node[fill,draw,circle,label=below left:$h$,minimum size=6,inner sep=-2]at(x,y){};+};

    \draw[densely dashed]
    (12pt,0) -- ++(0,-125pt)
    (18pt,0) -- ++(0,-125pt);
    \draw[|-|,line width=0.2pt] (0,-120pt)++(12pt,-4pt)-- ++(6pt,0) node[midway](n){};
    \draw[<-] (n.center) |- ++(10pt,-5pt) node [anchor=180, inner sep=0pt]{\tiny \verb+6pt+};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

PSD:

- Result scale is 3.5;
- In the code I use: `\draw[draw_style_opt](coordinate) node[node_style_opt]{node_text_content}`; instead `\node[node_style_opt] at (coordinate) {node_text_content}`; because `draw_style_opt` affects all styles within command line.