# Using node after pic results in error in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[corner/.pic = {
    \path[pic actions] (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) --cycle;
  }]

  \pic[draw] {corner} ++(1,0) node{hi};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates the following error:

> I do not know the key '/tikz/pics/hi' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \pic[draw] {corner} ++(1,0) node{hi}

It seems that TikZ interprets the node as a pic, and as a consequence tries to find the definition of a pic called `hi` instead of using `hi` as the text inside of the node.

By contrast, `\node{hi} ++(1,0) pic[draw] {corner};` works as expected.

Why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: You can turn off the parsing with `\path {pic[draw] {corner}} ++(1,0) node {hi};`

Comment: @percusse ah that's great! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it gladly. Is there any mention of this in the manual? The reason for this misbehaviour is still not clear to me...

Comment: This seems to be a bug in TikZ (at least in 3.0.0), note that `\path pic[draw] {corner} ++(1,0) node[draw] {corner};` is rendering the same as `\path pic[draw] {corner} ++(1,0) pic[draw] {corner};`.

Comment: @TonioElGringo has it been reported as a bug already? Should I open a ticket somewhere?

Comment: The bug has been reported [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/341/), and a possible solution is given [in this TeX.SE answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211613/shape-missing-using-pic-in-tikz/211615#211615)

Comment: @percusse Your solution correct the bug if I use pic directly in the path, but if I intsert it using `insert path=` I'm not able to solve the problem this way (I use Mark Wibrow's trick in this case).

Comment: @Kpym I'm actually not fixing the bug but limiting its effect. The node/pic parsing is designed as a greedy one but doesn't turn itself off after finishing so keeps parsing until the end. I don't think you need insert path if you are using pics though.

Comment: @percusse I would like to avoid using pic in `insert path`, but I don't know for the moment how to draw a point on the foreground layer without it (and without hack) : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217798/9335

Comment: I still think @percusse's trick can be very helpful as a workaround for simple cases and should be added as an answer either here or in the related question

Comment: It's already linked; it will show up to the right as a related question.