# TikZ: nodes and pics along path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put both nodes and pics along a path. This works perfectly well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{p/.pic={\node [circle, draw] at (0,0) {};}}
$\tikz{
  \draw (0,0) node {x} pic {p}
    to (1,1) pic {p};
}$
\end{document}
```

I get a path from (0,0) to (1,1), with a node labelled 'x' and my pic p at (0,0), and my pic p at (1,1).

But if I change my tikz picture to the following, I get errors:

```
$\tikz{
  \draw (0,0) node {x} pic {p}
    to (1,1) node {y};
}$
```

In fact, it seems that I can place some nodes, and then I can place some pics, but then I cannot place any more nodes along the path.

How can I achieve what I want? Is this a bug with PGF 3.0?

Comment: This is already [known bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/211615/9335).

Comment: @Kpym Please leave your comment as an answer.

Comment: @JamieVicary probably it is better to mark this question as duplicate. But I think that the question should not be deleted as his title and description are closer to the problem, compared to [the previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211613/9335).